# Entity Framework me devuelve Null

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Buenas Tengo este store

```
@CodRegistro    NVARCHAR(20) = NULL,
@UsuarioWindows NVARCHAR(11) = NULL,
@CodPersonal    CHAR(5) = NULL,
@IP             NVARCHAR(11) = NULL,
@TipoMetodo     INT,
@Query          NVARCHAR(50) = NULL,
@Pagina         INT = NULL,
@Cantidad       INT = NULL,
@Total          INT = NULL OUT

DECLARE @Desde AS INT       --Páginado
DECLARE @Hasta AS INT       --Páginado
SET @Desde = ((ABS(@Pagina - 1) * @Cantidad) + 1);
SET @Hasta = @Desde + @Cantidad - 1;

SELECT 
            @Total = ISNULL(COUNT(*), 0) 
        FROM 
            Presupuesto.RelacionCodigoUsuario RCU
        WHERE (
            RCU.CodPersonal LIKE '%' + @Query + '%' OR
            RCU.UsuarioWindows LIKE '%' + @Query + '%'
        );

        WITH  ConsultaCore AS(
            SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RCU.CodRegistro DESC) AS NRegistro,
                RCU.CodPersonal,
                RCU.CodRegistro,
                RCU.UsuarioWindows,
                RCU.FechaInsert,
                RCU.FechaModif,
                RCU.IPInsert,
                RCU.IPModif,
                RCU.UsuarioInsert,
                RCU.UsuarioModif,
                RCU.CodPersonal personal, 
                Presupuesto.GetCC1(RCU.CodPersonal) cc1
            FROM 
                Presupuesto.RelacionCodigoUsuario RCU
            WHERE (
                RCU.CodPersonal LIKE '%' + @Query + '%' OR
                RCU.UsuarioWindows LIKE '%' + @Query + '%'
            )
        )
        SELECT 
            cc.NRegistro
            ,cc.CodPersonal
            ,cc.CodRegistro
            ,cc.UsuarioWindows
            ,cc.FechaInsert
            ,cc.FechaModif
            ,cc.IPInsert
            ,cc.IPModif
            ,cc.UsuarioInsert
            ,cc.UsuarioModif
            ,cc.personal
            ,cc.cc1
        FROM ConsultaCore cc 
        WHERE @Desde <= cc.NRegistro AND @Hasta >= cc.NRegistro 
        ORDER BY cc.NRegistro ASC;
```

Bueno el store es lo de menos y funciona bien en el sql cuando le mando los parametros y todo, pero desde el Entity Framwork me devuelve la cantidad de registros bien pero todos null.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi codigo

```
public static List<RelacionCodigoUsuario> Buscar(string Query, int Pagina, int Cantidad, ref int Total)
    {
        List<RelacionCodigoUsuario> data = new List<RelacionCodigoUsuario>();
        CostosEntities context = new CostosEntities();
        int TipoMetodo = 0;
        data = context.Database.SqlQuery<RelacionCodigoUsuario>("Presupuesto.sp_PersonalCentroCosto @CodRegistro, @UsuarioWindows, @CodPersonal, @IP, @TipoMetodo, @Query, @Pagina, @Cantidad, @Total",
            new SqlParameter("@CodRegistro", DBNull.Value),
            new SqlParameter("@UsuarioWindows", DBNull.Value),
            new SqlParameter("@CodPersonal", DBNull.Value),
            new SqlParameter("@IP", DBNull.Value),
            new SqlParameter("@TipoMetodo", TipoMetodo),
            new SqlParameter("@Query", Query),
            new SqlParameter("@Pagina", Pagina),
            new SqlParameter("@Cantidad", Cantidad),
            new SqlParameter("@Total", Total)).ToList();
        return data;
    }
```

Y esta mi clase

```
public class RelacionCodigoUsuario
{
    public int NRegistro { get; set; }
    public string CodRegistro { get; set; }
    public string CodPersonal { get; set; }
    public string UsuarioWindows { get; set; }
    public string IPInsert { get; set; }
    public string IPModif { get; set; }
    public string UsuarioInsert { get; set; }
    public string UsuarioModif { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaInsert { get; set; }
    public DateTime? FechaModif { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: No veo que le mandes las variables Desde y Hasta

Comment: @Tuco no se envían, son variables del SP.

Comment: Estas seguro que estas usando los mismos valores de los parametros que en la prueba directa en SQL? Misma Pagina, mismo Query, etc?

Comment: @Tuco Si amigo, igual, y devuelve valores, lo que es raro que les asigna null en la imagen se ve, hace la consulta y devuelve rows, pero todos los campos son null.

Comment: Veo que el Select de tu SP no coincide al 100% con la definicion de tu clase, por ejemplo: el orden de CodRegistro y CodPersonal estan intercambiados, falta FechaInsert y FechaModif, tambien en el select agregas personal y cc1, los cuales no estan definidos en tu clase. Intenta igualar la clase de manera exacta

Comment: @Tuco Hasta donde sé el EF hace el bind de los valores por el nombre del campo, no por la posición, pero le cambie y no funciono, pero buena observación gracias.

Comment: Ademas, en tu SP tienes a "Total" como parametro de salida, esperas una  cantidad o una entidad?

Comment: Cambiaste el orden, que tal los campos que faltan y sobran?

Comment: Si, tambien lo recibe bien, en ese parametro no hay problema, el problema son los resultados del list

Comment: Los campos bien, no hay ninguna queja, ejecutan el select, los resultados (columnas), siguen siendo null, osea mira la variable `@total`devuelve bien 1 registro los rows tambien son 1, pero los campos todos null, ese es el problema.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56191/discussion-between-tuco-and-gabriel-jeremy-rodriguez-river).

Answer (score 1):

Aconsejaria implemente un ejemplo simple del procedure para validar su funcionamiento

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_PersonalCentroCosto
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT 
        0 as NRegistro,
        CodRegistro,
        CodPersonal,
        UsuarioWindows,
        IPInsert,
        IPModif,
        UsuarioInsert,
        UsuarioModif,
        FechaInsert,
        FechaModif
    FROM Presupuesto.RelacionCodigoUsuario 
    ORDER BY cc.NRegistro ASC;

END


public static List<RelacionCodigoUsuario> Buscar(string Query, int Pagina, int Cantidad, ref int Total)
{

    List<RelacionCodigoUsuario> data = null;

    using(CostosEntities context = new CostosEntities())
    {
        data = context.Database.SqlQuery<RelacionCodigoUsuario>("Presupuesto.sp_PersonalCentroCosto").ToList();
    }

    return data;
}
```

que la implementacion sea simple, pero valida que de esta forma funciona, despues puede ir agregando parametros y demas complejidad para ver que causa el problema con el mapping de los campos

Veras que en el procedure respete el orden de las propiedades ademas de retornar exactamente las que defines en la clases (por eso quite el `personal` y `cc1` del select)